# How to pass parameters to a JavaScript library and how to call it multiple times with different input sets on the same web page

Tags: javascript

I've been asked to modify some JavaScript code that looks something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var text1="foo";
    var text2="bar"
</script>
<script src="/process.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code takes inputs text1 & text2, does some image processing, and displays the resulting image in the div in the body. How can I modify it so that the JavaScript library can be called multiple times on different input values on the same HTML page, something (in effect) like the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var image_width=100;
    var image_height=200;
</script>
<script>
    var image_width=50;
    var image_height=150;
</script>

<script src="/process.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code in process.js is something like this:

```
var cc1 = $('#canvas_container');
var ctx1 = cc1[0].getContext('2d');

function make_image(){
   $('#container').width(image_width);
   $('#container').height(image_height);
   var cntnr = document.getElementById('container');
   var c1 = document.createElement("canvas");
   c1.width = image_width;
   c1.height = image_height;
   c1.id = "canvas_container";
   cntnr.appendChild(c1);
   // image generation code here
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: we have to see what's inside process.js to help you

Comment: Yes, you should definitely post your code. Your library should probably expose a function which should receive the required parameters as arguments.

Comment: please choose an other id for the second div. the id used to be unique.

Comment: OK, I've posted process.js above. I can expose a function but where do I call it in the HTML page?

Comment: Calling a library twice... That's not how libraries work. A library contains functions. Functions must be built functionaly, this means you put the id of the container as a parameter, not hard coded. And don't ever have two elements with the same id (otherwise it cannot be used as identification). Solutions to your problem will not look like the answers you are waiting for

Comment: I understand that I can expose a function, such as init() in JavaScript and call it from the HTML file multiple times, but how do I call it? In HTML, I can have two separate containers, but where do I call the JavaScript function for each of two divs?
   `<div id="container1"></div>
    <div id="container2"></div>`

Comment: @Emmanuel-Delay I'm getting clarity on this. So now my only question is how do I call this function, say init("foo", "bar") so that when the page loads the JavaScript library executes and updates the container in the div from which the function was called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(EDIT: wasn't this a Google Maps question, yesterday? If not, I should give another example)

Let me just show you how you can use parameters in functions.

---

Your example:
So, process.js contains the functions.  Calling those functions, you do outside that file.

Notice: Your example doesn't show anything visible on the screen.  But the two canvas elements are there.

The point is: anything that isn't general for all instances, you should put in a parameter.

index.php

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="process.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {  // do this so the script waits until the page is loaded
      // image1
      make_image('container1', 'canvas1', 100, 200);
      // image2
      make_image('container2', 'canvas2', 50, 150);
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container1"></div>
    <div id="container2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

process.js

```
function make_image(container, canvas_id, width, height) {
   $('#' + container).width(width);
   $('#' + container).height(height);

   var cntnr = document.getElementById(container);
   var c1 = document.createElement("canvas");
   c1.width = width;
   c1.height = height;
   c1.id = canvas_id;
   cntnr.appendChild(c1);
   // image generation code here
}
```

---

Google Maps example

So, anything about initialize() that is specific to 1 map, must be set in the parameters.  Example: if you want a different zoom on map1/map2, put another parameter 'zoom', next to lng, and call one with zoom 18, one with zoom 15.  Try it out.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  #container1, #container2 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script>
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996197/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-javascript-library-and-how-to-call-it-multiple-times?noredirect=1#comment50061772_30996197
  // gets triggered twice, by page_is_loaded()
  function initialize(container_id, lat, lng) {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      var mapProp = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 17,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
      };
      var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(container_id),mapProp);
      return map;  // by doing this, who ever calls this function has the map object, to do what ever one wants.
  }
  // gets triggered when the page is loaded
  function page_is_loaded() {
    var map1 = initialize('container1', 50.89515421660153, 4.341372907161713);    // Atomium, Brussels, Belgium
    var map2 = initialize('container2', 53.34184485510149, -6.286933958530426);  // Guinness Storehouse, Dublin, Irish Republic

    // let's put a marker on map1, at the atomium, on the parking lot, where I left my car
    var marker_atomium = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.895783519434076, 4.339616060256958),
      map: map1
    });

  }
  // this triggers page_is_loaded(), to be triggered when the DOM of the page is loaded
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', page_is_loaded);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container1"></div>
  <div id="container2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```